# Servlet: Output file with server side include, text and dynamically created image

Tags: image, servlets, dynamic

I have a servlet in which I want to output normal text and also dynamically created images.

The generated web page has a header and footer included with

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("header.jsp").include(request, response);
```

Doing that lead to an expection:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

I can I achieve this? (Header, text, image, text, footer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image must not be streamed in the same request as the HTML page: the generated HTML must be :

```
header
text
<img src="path/to/servlet/streaming/the/image/bytes"/>
text
footer
```

When loading this HTML page, the browser will trigger a second request to `path/to/servlet/streaming/the/image/bytes`, and the servlet mapped to this path should use the response output stream to send the dynamically generated image bytes.